# printf %6.2f in scheme or racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do you get a `printf %6.2f` in scheme or racket, as you would in C?

Right now all I have is `printf "The area of the disk is ~s\n" ( - d1 d2)`, but I can't format the output to a specific floating point format.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To get a behavior closer to C's `printf()` function use the `format` procedure provided by [SRFI-48](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-48.html), like this:

```
(require srfi/48)
(format "The area of the disk is ~6,2F~%" (- d1 d2))
```

A more verbose alternative would be to use Racket's built-in [`~r`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~r#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29) procedure, as suggested by @stchang:

```
(string-append
 "The area of the disk is "
 (~r (- d1 d2) #:min-width 6 #:precision '(= 2))
 "\n")
```

Comment: And in [tag:Scheme] you just include `(srfi :48)` amongst the imports instead of the `require` form.

Comment: Maybe I should start a separate question about this but, how is "srfi/48" a good name? In other languages you'd require "text" or "formatting".

Answer (score 4):

Racket has [`~r`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~r#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29).

You'll probably want to provide `#:min-width` and `#:precision` arguments.